# Convert object into multi query parameter Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to generate swagger documentation with query parameters from an object but I'm not sure if it's possible with springdoc-openapi. I know this is possible with io.springfox.

What I want is to create a single object, add all the fields to this object and then have these fields presented in the swagger documentation as individual query parameters.

E.g of test cases:

1. Test case 1
   For following code:
   [image]
   The following swagger documentation is generated:
   [image]
2. Test case 2:
   For the following code:
   [image]
   The following swagger documentation is generated:
   [image]

In both situations the services works as expected with query parameters. What I want is to have code from test case 2 to generate the same documentation from test case 1. I know this is possible with springfox but I can not figure out how to do it in springdoc-openapi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to decorate the TestCase class with the `@ParameterObject` annotation :

```
@ParameterObject
public class TestCase {
    @Parameter
    String field1;
    @Parameter
    String field2;
    @Parameter
    String field1;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you :)

Comment: I have tried to add a description to `field1` using `@Parameter(description = "foo")` and doesn't seem to work. It's like if ignored it (same with `name` and others). Any idea what this could be?